# Trim method in databinding android

Tags: android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

Is it possible `trim()` method is work on two ways data binding, when getting info from XML. If yes how?

```
android:text='@={contact.contactDetails.name}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can trim it in getter/setter method of you model class.

```
public class UserModel {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name.trim();
    }
}
```

android get it with `binding.getUser().getName()` , even you can use trim() in `getName()` both will work same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me, neither trim() not trim in layout didn't work. My decision was create new method, that replaced all spaces at string.

```
Utils.class
public static String trim(String string) {
        return string.replaceAll(" ", "");
    }
```

And then in layout:

```
android:text="@{Utils.trim(contact.contactDetails.name)}"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is also possible:

`android:text='@={contact.contactDetails.name.trim}'`